# Cython compile module in separate directory

Tags: python, cython, cythonize

I am a newbie to cython.

I've the following directory structure.

```
cython_program/
cython_program/helloworld.py
cython_program/lib/printname.py
```

**helloworld.py**:

```
import lib.printname as name

def printname():
    name.myname()
```

**printname.py:**

```
def myname():
    print("this is my name")
```

**setup.py:**

```
from distutils.core import setup
from distutils.extension import Extension
from Cython.Distutils import build_ext

ext_modules = [
    Extension("helloworld",  ["helloworld.py"]),
    Extension("mod",  ["./lib/printname.py"]),
]

setup(
    name = 'My Program',
    cmdclass = {'build_ext': build_ext},
    ext_modules = ext_modules
)
```

The problem I am having is that when I compile my program using `python setup.py build_ext --inplace` in the `cython_program` directory. It does compile the program successfully and generates a `printname.c` file in the lib folder.

But when I move the printname.py and helloworld.py to a separate folder to make sure that my cython compiled code is running. It gives me the following error  `ImportError: No module named lib.printname`.

Why isn't it compiling the module(lib.printname) also with the main `helloworld.py` file ?

**Note:** This works fine if I keep both helloworld.py and printname.py in the same folder.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: consider accepting your own answer...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It was a simple issue in `setup.py`.

Changed this line:

```
Extension("mod",  ["./lib/printname.py"]),
```

To This:

```
Extension("lib.printname",  ["./lib/printname.py"]),
```